# Error with Process.Start: Interface Database

Tags: c#, process.start

While trying to open a program with Process.Start in MVS2010 with C# I get the following error message:

> "iecmilib.dll: Unable to allocate interface database descriptions"

and the next window shows the following:

> "Unable to initialize the interface library!"

The software is installed in my compurter and works fine when opened directly. It seems to be some problem with the library only when opening with the C#.
I have tried the following codes, which are basically the same:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\'path'\iecmint.exe")
```

and

```
Process IECM = new Process();
IECM.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:'path'\iecmint.exe";
IECM.Start();
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `WorkingDirectory` on the StartInfo?

Comment: I have now, thank you very much! I'm just beginning at this!

Answer (score 0):

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = "iecmint.exe";
info.UseShellExecute = true;
info.Verb = "runas";
info.WorkingDirectory = // Path To iecmint.exe

Process.Start(info);
```